# Variable loses value on if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple HTML layout as a test page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  <script>var user = 'test';</script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
       if(!user) {
          var user = '0';
       }
       alert(user);
  });
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

For some reason when checking the value of `!user` using the if condition, the condition is successful and the variable `user` gets the new value of `0` although I defined it previously. This has been driving me crazy for sometime now. Is there something wrong with the above code?

Comment: you set a new variable `var user`, not the existing one. Remove the `var`

Comment: @user3153169 That still doesn't explain why the `if` statement is running at all.

Comment: `if(!0)` evaluates to true

Comment: @Scimonster variable declarations in JavaScript are hoisted to the opening of the function.

Comment: @user3153169 Yeah, but `user` should be defined before that runs.

Comment: @Pointy I'm pretty sure that's how it works with function blocks, but not variable declarations.

Comment: @Scimonster well the question itself is clear evidence that that's how it actually works (because it does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've **redeclared** "user" as a local variable in the function.  Variable definitions in functions are always treated as if they occur at the very start of the function, meaning your code is equivalent to

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       var user;
       if(!user) {
          user = '0';
       }
       alert(user);
  });
```

At the `if` statement, the value of "user" will be `undefined`. The `!user` test succeeds, and so your code proceeds to set the variable to `'0'`.

Comment: but this condition anyway is not applicable so everything inside should be ignored or am I missing something?

Comment: Read my amendments to the answer.

Comment: i mean why the if condition is actually running when I previously declared the user variable?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel because the `var` statement is hoisted to the top of the function. Look at the code in my answer - that's the way JavaScript interprets your function. The `if` statement is testing the **local** "user", not the global one.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel change `var user = '0';` to `user = '0';` and you will see. [Fiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/nev2sj9y/).

Answer (score 1):

When DOM is loading variable 'user' is undefined. And in JavaScript (!undefined) is true, thus you are getting zero as output.